# Are using SDKs like Facebook PHP/JS SDK optional?

Tags: rest, sdk, oauth-2.0

Just like the title says, Are using SDKs like Facebook PHP/JS SDK optional? Can I make my own library to access a REST api with OAuth/2 without using the SDKs they provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically? Sure. Nobody's forcing you to do anything or use any library. But if you use the API incorrectly they might not like it and you will be responsible. So unless there is some specific reason to do it yourself, rather use the libraries provided.